# How to persist several rows in a @OneToMany relationship with a composite key

Tags: jpa

I have found this **OLD** link which resolve my database schema:

http://randomthoughtsonjavaprogramming.blogspot.com.es/2014/09/jpa-manytoone-with-composite-primary-key.html

I can retrieve data and everything works great, but I don't know how to insert data as I posted to the author.

In my case for every guild inserted I need to insert several guildranks at the same time, so one use case will be:

BEGIN TRANSACTION

**GUILD**

```
Guildname1
```

**GUILDRANK**

```
Guildname1, 1
Guildname1, 2
Guildname1, 3
Guildname1, 4
```

END TRANSACTION

Any suggestions?
Thanks

UPDATE

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "Cuestionario.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Cuestionario c")
 })
public class Cuestionario implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cuestionario", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST })
    private Set<Hoja> hojas;

}



@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "Hoja.findAll", query = "SELECT h FROM Hoja h")
public class Hoja implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private HojaPK id;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to Cuestionario
    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE })
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Cuestionario cuestionario;

    public Hoja() {
    }

}

@Embeddable
public class HojaPK implements Serializable {
    // default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    //Correspond with "id" in Cuestionario 
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;

    private int dia;

    public HojaPK() {
    }
}
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="pu"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">


        <properties>

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="***" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="***" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=mydatabase" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
                value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />


            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <!--  
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            -->
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

TestCase.java

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pu");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();

        em.persist(cuestionario);
        em.flush();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 32; i++) {
            HojaPK hojaPk = new HojaPK(cuestionario.getId(), i);
            Hoja hoja = new Hoja();
            hoja.setId(hojaPk);
            em.persist(hoja);
        }


em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();
emf.close();
```

Comment: Here's an idea, post your entities, and the persistence code you use to persist them. Then look in the log of the JPA provider and see what it does. Then look in the database to see what is there. Then do a retrieve and see what it retrieves.

Comment: Your coce doesn't insert anything. What have you tried?

Comment: As a I said at the beginning I have no idea. I need to insert one row in Cuestionario with the generated ID and at the same time several rows un Hoja with the id of cuestionario and día assigned by hand

Comment: Then do just that. Create a Cuestionatio, insert it, get its ID, then create the 4 Hojas and persist them.

Comment: Thanks, Works ok, I hope to not have problems with the transactions